# How can I merge outputs of two separate layers so that the overall performance improves?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, keras, performance

I am training a combined model (fine-tuned VGG16 for images and shallow FCN for numerical data) to do a binary classification. However, the overall AUC score is not what I expected it to be.

Image-only mean AUC after 5-fold cross-validation is about ***0.73*** and numeric data only 5-fold mean AUC is ***0.65***. I was hoping to improve the mean AUC by combining the models into one and merging output layers using `concatenate` in Keras.

```
img_output = Dense(256, activation="sigmoid")(x_1)
```

and

```
numeric_output = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x_2)
```

are the output layers of the two models. And,

```
concat = concatenate([img_output, numeric_output])
hidden1 = Dense(64, activation="relu")(concat)
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(hidden1)
```

is the way I concatenated them.

Since image-only performance was better I decided that it might be reasonable to have more dense layers for `image_output` (`256`) and ended up using `128` in `numeric_output`.I could only reach up to mean AUC of 0.67 using a combined model. I think I should rearrange the concatenation of two outputs somehow (by introducing another learnable parameter (like the formula (10) at 3.3 section of [this work](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cin/2018/2061516/)?, bias?, or something else) to get more boost on mean AUC. However, I was not able to find what options were available.

Hope you have some ideas worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible to help much because this is an experimental question. I'm afraid the only answer comes with testing many different options.

I see a little thing that might be making your model a little worse, though:

- You're concatenating "relu" with "sigmoid".

Placing two different nature values in the same array may make it more difficult for updating weights properly.

A few independent suggestions:

- Make the output of the images model have "relu" activation as well before the concatenation. Preferrably, use a batch normalization before the image relu and before the number relu (this way you concatenate values that are in very similar ranges).
- Instead of concatenating, you can try `Multiply()([img_output, numeric_output])`, in this case, both outputs must have the same size, one of them uses "relu" or "linear", and the other uses "sigmoid".

---

Now, something important when using AUC: you need big batch sizes, because AUC is dependent on the whole data, it's not like usual metrics/losses that you can take the mean from the results of each batch.

Comment: Thank you for insights. let me try them. BTW, why do you think, if multiplied, one should have "relu" or "linear", and the other "sigmoid"?

Comment: To keep roughly the same range as the other layers. Sigmoid is between 0 and 1, and ReLU is from 0 to unknown. Multiplying two ReLUs may produce blowing values, too high, multiplying two Sigmoids may decrease the values too much. Use a balanced multiplication.